# How do I get Detailed Logging working?

Tags: logging, db-logging

Using the documentation, I've created a new database for my detailed logging data - I already had one for the CMS (Drupal) and one for Civi - and I've added the details for that database into my civicrm.settings.php file. I've turned on detailed logging via the Preferences page. I can see that the database has been populated and is storing lots of records.

So far so good.

But when I try to view the Change Log for any contact record, all I get is a spinning Civi icon.

Have I missed a step? How do I debug (there's nothing visible in the Civi log)?

running CiviCRM 5.45.0

Comment: Spinning icon usually means error 500 which means check the webserver log. There might also be something in the browser dev tools network tab response, but it doesn't usually have details.

Comment: Looking at changess can take a while - does it still spin when looking at a contact with very few changes?

Comment: I tried it with various records, and left it to see if it was working, but just very slowly. I ended up getting a network error. Might have been timing out?

Answer (score 3):

Reading around the issue reported above I came across this extension - https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.innodbtriggers - which I've now installed, and it appears to have resolved my issue. I'm now seeing a prompt result when looking at the change log.

Maybe this extension is essential when setting up detailed logging using a separate database?

Comment: I think the extension adds indexes into all the tables and changes them from ARCHIVE to Innodb format (you can't have indexes on ARCHIVE tables). This means a must faster response time but if you have a large database (5million + contacts and assoiated records) then you'd see a increase in storage size. For most users this isn't an issue, so you're probably fine.